# flatironjs and Cloud9; window is undefined error?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, flatiron.js

Anyone else having luck using flatironjs with the Cloud9 ide?

In my **server.js** file I have:

```
require("coffee-script"); 
var app = require("./app");

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Then in my **app.coffee** file I have:

```
flatiron = require "flatiron"
director = require "director"

app = flatiron.app
app.use flatiron.plugins.http

module.exports = app.router.get "/", ->
res.writeHead 200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" }
res.end "Hello world!\n"
```

When I attempt to run this in the Cloud9 IDE I get the following:

```
node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        **^ ReferenceError: window is not defined**
    at Object. (/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/broadway/node_modules/eventemitter2/lib/eventemitter2.js:547:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:302:12)
    at require (module.js:355:19)
    at Object. (/node_modules/flatiron/node_modules/broadway/lib/broadway/app.js:11:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:411:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:31)
```

If I create a standard http server without using flatiron everything runs great:

```
http = require "http"
module.exports = http.createServer (req, res) ->
res.writeHead 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
res.end "Hello World\n"
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in EventEmitter running on Solaris. You can see it as well if you just run an app on the latest version of Solaris, will crash with the same error message. You can use the [patched EventEmitter2](https://github.com/c9/EventEmitter2) that removes the check for the browser.

I created [an issue](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2/issues/58) for you.

Comment: So, got the patched EventEmitter2 which gets me past the original window undefined issue. However, now I receive a "Cannot call method 'listen' of undefined" error.

Answer (score 1):

So there's some code at the [bottom of that eventemitter2.js file](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2/blob/master/lib/eventemitter2.js#L547) that basically tries to be "isomorphic" and work in both node.js and a browser. It tries to guess which environment by testing for the following global variables being defined:

- process
- process.title
- exports

If all of those are defined, eventemitter2 will attach it's exported properties to the `exports` object for use in node.js. Otherwise, it will attach them to the `window` object for use in a browser.

For some reason inside cloud9, 1 or more of those 3 global variables is not defined, and it's branching to "browser" mode assuming `window` is there and failing. I don't know enough about the cloud9 ide hosting environment to understand exactly which one (or 2 or 3) of them it is and why it's missing.

Your vanilla `http` code works because it doesn`t load eventemitter2, which IS loaded when you use flatiron, which depends on broadway, which depends on eventemitter2.

Comment: Right, I follow that. I was more curious if anyone who is using Cloud9 has been able get flatiron up and running. I have confirmed the process object is available. However, as the error states the window object is undefined...

Comment: what about process.title and exports?

Comment: process.title appears to be blank. When I try to console.log it nothing appears but, it is not undefined. exports is not undefined.

Comment: Hmm. Weird. Try the cloud9 guys via email or IRC I guess.

Comment: Cloud9 guy here. We found out about this as well because we use forever for some services, and that won't run anymore as well. We've released a patched version of EventEmitter2 and reported a bug on that project.

Comment: Yup, looks like it got fixed and merged. https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2/pull/52